# Flutter - Is it possible to call a page from a Flutter PieChart click?

Tags: flutter-layout, pie-chart

I need to call a page in the application by clicking on the PieChart area.

I'm using the 'charts_flutter' package.

I managed to do the following scenario:

1 - Through selectionModels -> changedListener, I can call a test page (using MaterialPageRoute ());

2 - To work with the previous item, I cannot use the defaultRenderer property of PieChart because redirection to the test page does not work;

3 - I need to use the defaultRenderer because it is a necessity to have the customized PieChart arc;

Basically the need is to call another page in the application when clicking on an area of ​​PieChart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but I'm routing to a page when the user presses on a pie slice using selectionModels as follows:

```
new charts.PieChart(
  series,
  animate: true,
  defaultRenderer: arcRendererConfig,
  selectionModels: [
    new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
      changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/mypage');
      },
    )
  ],
);
```

If you need to know what pie slice was pressed, you can get the index into your dataset with:

```
model.selectedDatum[0].index
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response, it worked for me. @Ed Pfromer